# multi Inheritance class in library

Tags: c++, header, lib

I try to use a template in my lib, but a have an error. (**I have already set the entire template in header**)

in the exe : main.cpp

```
#include "../lib/Lib.h"
class Test
{
   public:
       Test(){}

       void test(){}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   Lib<Test>* test = new Lib<Test>();
   test->execute();

   return 0;
}
```

In dynamic lib : lib.h :

```
template<class T>
class __declspec(dllexport) Sub : public T
{
    public:
        Sub();
        virtual ~Sub();
};

template<class T>
Sub<T>::Sub(){};


template<class T>
Sub<T>::~Sub(){};


template<class T>
class __declspec(dllexport) Lib : private Sub<T>
{
    public:
        Lib();

        void execute();

    private:
        ~Lib();
};

template<class T>
Lib<T>::Lib(){};


template<class T>
Lib<T>::~Lib(){};


template<class T>
void Lib<T>::execute()
{
    this->test();
}
```

that won't compile, why ? (undefined reference) maybe a link error.

That seem to be related to virtual.

thanks for the help !!!

```
..\lib\Lib.h:22: 
erreur : undefined reference to `Sub<Test>::Sub()'
:-1: erreur : debug/main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV3SubI4TestE[_ZTV3SubI4TestE]+0x10): undefined reference to `Sub<Test>::~Sub()'
:-1: erreur : debug/main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV3SubI4TestE[_ZTV3SubI4TestE]+0x18): undefined reference to `Sub<Test>::~Sub()'
:-1: erreur : debug/main.o: in function `Lib<Test>::~Lib()':
..\lib\Lib.h:26: erreur : undefined reference to `Sub<Test>::~Sub()'
:-1: erreur : collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
:-1: erreur : [Makefile.Debug:68: debug/exe.exe] Error 1
```

Comment: Please include the exact error message in the question.  Also missing definition of `Sub::Sub()` and `Sub::~Sub()`. Also mission definition of `Test::Test()`.  Please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry it's a snippet. I correct it.

Comment: Short answer: templates are inline by nature. You cannot export them.